# Magento IE-7 Fix In Windows XP

Tags: internet-explorer, magento, windows-xp

My Magento Site was giving a lot of javascript errors in IE-7 and IE-9.
Hence I forced mysite to IE-8 document mode by using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

It fixed all the problems but not for windows XP.
When i check my site with IE-6 and IE-7 running on a XP some of prototype.js functions seem to fail.

So can any one tell me if there any fix for IE running on XP.

FYI : Site is running perfect in all IE - versions on windows-7 and Vista.

ERRORS : **SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'childElements': object is null or undefined**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your url or list of errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a Fix For the compatibility issue :-

```
  <!--[if gte IE 7]>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />         
  <![endif]-->
```

As previously I used the meta tag openly it was forcing browsers without IE-8 support to qurik mode & so it was breaking.